# Is anything special about the Pythagorean triple generator $(3u^k,1)$?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

A *Pythagorean triple generator*  (PTG) is a pair of positive integers $(p,q)$, conventionally taken with $p>q$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$, from which one constructs a Pythagorean triple $(p^2-q^2,2pq,p^2+q^2)$. Evidently, all positive integers can be either element in a PTG.

Is anything special about a Pythagorean triangle (or triple) constructed from a PTG of the form $(3u^k,1)$ for integers $u\ge 1$ and $k \ge 2$? For example, does the resulting triangle/triple have any curious or special properties?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to think that it might?  (Or, a slightly different way of phrasing the question, 'why 3'?)

Comment: This generator popped out of an equation I was manipulating — I know the original equation has no solutions with $k > 1$, so I thought this PTG might have some special property I could exploit.